# Save and import inkscape progress with multiple layers

Tags: vector-graphics, inkscape

I have started to learn vector graphic design with Inkscape and having an issue while saving my progress. My current progress has multiple layers and when I save it as an SVG and import it, all the layers are combined as one. I feel this is a simple problem but my google search skills couldn't help me find the answer.

So is there a way to save your Inkscape progress along with layers and edit history so you can import the progress and start from where you had stopped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to find the solution. https://forum.inkscapecommunity.com/index.php?topic=384.msg2743#msg2743

So when we `import` the saved SVG we lose the layers. But when we `open` the SVG the layers will be there as we left it.